# Clickhouse UDF not passing argumnets as expected

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, clickhouse

I've created UDF in Clickhouse, for example:

```
create function test_function AS (in_param)  -> (select col1 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.key where t1.key = in_param);
```

It works fine when I try the following example, just passing the string value excplicitly:

```
select test_function('10000');
```

But the following example fails:

```
select test_function(x_id) from tablex where colx='somevalue';
```

Fails with error:

```
Code: 47. DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'x_id' while processing query: 'select col1 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.key where t1.key = x_id'
```

As if the value of x_id is not passed to the function, looks like the function is working with string 'x_id' and not the value of field x_id. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced the similar not obvious behavior in Clickhouse.

Clickhouse passes column `x_id` as `in_param`, but there is no such column in table1 and table2

```
select col1 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.key where t1.key = in_param
```

So the query fails.

When I asked about this behavior in Clikhouse developers telegram chat, they answered me that's expected behavior because of performance considerations.

The only solution is to use dictionaries instead of `table1` and `table2` and use `dictGet` in UDF body instead of querying regular tables.